# Testing Android Instant Apps

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I'm developing Android Instant App for my published app. However, published version of my installable app does not include the necessary URLs in application manifest file. Before I release my app, I want to add the URLs into my application manifest file and see how it works when the user directs to the URL I define for the Instant App. Any way to test this scenario without updating my app?

I mean a way to test Instant App without launching URL but going through the user scenario?

**Note: I uploaded necessary JSON files to my web server, however, because my installable app does not include the URLs, it didn't release it. But the test URL verifies that it has been successfully associated with my website.**

Comment: Testing instant apps is currently very raw. As for Espresso, there is no support for multi-feature apps. Only single feature app can be tested - see a bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/4/issues/77502630

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test the InstantApp process by uploading your APK to the beta environment of the googlePlay (and add yourself as a tester).

You can test your app's functionality (running as an instant app) by adding the proper Run/Debug Configurations and adding parameters that you need following this guideline:

you have to use the `app links assistant` in Tools->App Links Assistant

Then check your links and in the *Path selector*, check whether the `pathPrefix` option is selected.

Then at the bottom of the OnCreate method of your activity (which is related to the link you recently edited) add this code:

```
Intent appLinkIntent = getIntent();
String appLinkAction = appLinkIntent.getAction();
Uri appLinkData = appLinkIntent.getData();
// then use appLinkData.getQueryParameter("YourParameter")
```

You can test and debug this, using the `editConfigurations` option.Just open that window and edit your instantApp module (the one launched with the Link you recently edited) and in the URL field add the URL parameters that you need. `?Param1=1&Param2=two` (then just run that module).

Answer (score 3):

*If I want to test my instant app on a pre-release track through the Google Play, do I still need to have an installable app APK published?*

To test your instant app's deployment through the Google Play on the development track, you must have the installable version of your app in a "draft" form in the Google Play Console.

For more information about deploying and testing the deployment of your instant app, see [Distribute your instant app](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7381861).